# Incorrect value in javascript from PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I just want to start by saying I am not a JavaScript developer, I am new to this.

Ok, so, I have a session value called id, this is a long (example: 76561198237133252) and I am passing this as a argument for a method. The issue is the id is not correct when the function is actually ran.

JS:

```
function sendMessage(id) 
{
    var message = $("#message").val();
    if (message)
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'addChatMessage.php', 
            type: 'POST', 
            data: '&id=' + id+ '&message=' + message, 
            dataType: 'text', 
            success: function (data) 
            {
                $('#chatMessages').load(document.URL +  ' #chatMessages');
                document.getElementById('message').value = '';
                $('#chatScrollable').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 1000);

                window.alert("Id: " + id);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="chat-input">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message..." required>
        <!-- <input type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php //echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>"> -->
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" id="msgButton" type="button" onclick="sendMessage(<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>);">Send</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show the relevent html

Comment: please show your html, from where you are calling `sendMessage()`?

Comment: Added @JamesFreund devpro

Comment: if session is working fine than you can use like `onclick="sendMessage('<?php echo $_SESSION["id"]; ?>');"`

Comment: Change `type: 'POST'` to `type: 'GET'` because you're sending data to the server as a query string.

Comment: "*the id is not correct*" Is the `id` *ever* correct? At what point are you receiving the *correct* `id` in the script?

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode()` in PHP to convert a PHP value to the corresponding Javascript literal. It will encode it properly to keep the same data type (e.g. putting quotes around a string).

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="msgButton" type="button" onclick="sendMessage(<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($_SESSION['id'])); ?>);">Send</button>
```

You also need to use `htmlentities()` to convert the quotes around the string to entities. Otherwise, the quote will match the quote after `onclick=`, and end the attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript is both awesome and aggravating for this one reason: it auto-converts strings and numbers to make sense of impossible statements. Your id is a number, so it might not be converting to a string properly. Use the `.toString()` of id to fix this problem.

Comment: This may sound dumb but where would I use this?

Comment: Since the id is sent as part of a query string it is a string already.

Comment: The problem he's having is when he substitutes `$_SESSION['id']` into the `onclick="sendMessage()`.